# How to Export Each Pagination Page individually to Excel of ag grid Data using angularjs wihtout selecitng

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using pagination  for my ag grid to display the 1000 files data.Know i want to export each page data individually to excel .

Answer (score 2):

The export functionality that is built into ag-grid is fairly simple, and not really suited to doing very specialized operations.

I suggest that you intercept the export event, and provide your own functionality, from your back-end code, that exports your data however you would like. There are libraries for most languages that write Excel files.

Comment: Thank you but ag grid is using third party to export total data . So when I try to do that it is not working thank you for your reply

Comment: @harishchintalapati The ag-grid [excel export module](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/tree/master/enterprise-modules/excel-export) source code is easily accessible. There is no "third party" involved.